# After renewing an ESTA, do I have to do anything for Global Entry too?

Tags: usa, passports, esta, global-entry

As per [this CBP FAQ entry for Global Entry](https://www.cbp.gov/faqs/i-am-current-global-entry-member-how-do-i-update-my-passport-information), I know that if you renew your passport (but not change your name), you need to log into the [GOES website](https://goes-app.cbp.dhs.gov/) to record your new passport details.

Fairly soon, my ESTA is expiring, and I'll need to pay the fee and go through the online system to get a new one issued for the next 24 months. When I had my Global Entry interview, they needed details of my current ESTA, so I guess there's some sort of link / checking.

So, once I've renewed my ESTA, what about telling Global Entry about it? Do I need to update anything in the GOES site or elsewhere about my new ESTA? Or will it then be automatic based on passport details?

(I couldn't find a FAQ entry for this on the CBP site)

Comment: Did you try logging into the GOES site to see whether it has a facility to accept updated ESTA information?

Comment: @phoog The "Update Documents" link only lets me provide new Passport or Driving License details, and "Manage Membership" seems to all be read-only. I might be missing something though!

Comment: Have you tried calling 866-530-4172

Answer (score 6):

I was on a student visa (F1) when I got GlobalEntry, and I asked what happens when I move back and use ESTA. The CBP person told me that both ESTA and GlobalEntry are both CBP programs, so they share information CBP will know about my new ESTA, and I don't need to do anything for GlobalEntry. Considering this, I think it's safe to assume they would know about renewed ESTA as well.